# How can I setup a trigger in Bamboo if there is a specific tag been pushed to my bitbucket repository

Tags: continuous-integration, bitbucket, release, bamboo, release-management

I am trying to use bamboo to manage my release procedure and just wondering if this is feasible:

1. The developer finished the integration test at local environment
2. The developer create a specific tag, e.g. "UAT_1.0.0" and pushed the tag to bitbucket
3. Bamboo sensed that there is an new tag "UAT_1.0.0" has been created on bitbucket and then start the building process; after that it will deploy the war file to the UAT server
4. Tester signed off the UAT and created a tag "REL_1.0.0" and pushed the tag to bitbucket
5. Bamboo sensed the new tag "REL_1.0.0" and start the building process. After build finished, it deploy the war file to the PROD server

It looks like the "Repository triggers the build when changes are committed" is to best way to implement the process. But I can't find out the way to move any further. Any idea?

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can do this (Only if you can deploy custom plugins to it).

You need to build custom triggers as plugins for bamboo.

1. Get/Install the [SDK](https://developer.atlassian.com/docs/getting-started/set-up-the-atlassian-plugin-sdk-and-build-a-project)
2. Create a plugin. See [here](https://developer.atlassian.com/display/BAMBOODEV/Trigger+Reason+Module#TriggerReasonModule-SampleModuleDescriptorElement). 
   If you have access to bamboo's source code I suggest you look into classes `DependencyTriggerReason`, `InitialbuildTriggerReason`, `ScheduledTriggerReason`. You need to create a class implementing [TriggerReason](https://docs.atlassian.com/atlassian-bamboo/latest/com/atlassian/bamboo/v2/build/trigger/TriggerReason.html). You should start with [this](https://developer.atlassian.com/display/BAMBOODEV/Introduction+to+writing+Tasks) tutorial if you are new to developing bamboo plugins.
3. Deploy it to bamboo.

Answer (score 0):

A bit late but... I found a solution. You need to put a "negative" regular expression in the "Exclude changesets" section in the repository configuration, that include the word that you want.
The regular expression is like :

^(?!.*test).*$

like that: [repository configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qOzzE.png)

with this, bamboo will only build commits with this word in the message.
Now, if your commit is like "commit for test", bamboo will build it